# Not able to take backup of hypertable TimescaleDB database using pg_dump PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

**command used to take backup**

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin>pg_dump  -h localhost -U postgres -p 5432  -Fc -f "D:\Database Backup\temp_10.bak" GESEMS_Performace_Test.
```

**Error :**

> pg_dump: NOTICE:  hypertable data are in the chunks, no data will be copied.

> DETAIL:  Data for hypertables are stored in the chunks of a hypertable so COPY TO of a hypertable will
> not copy any data.

[image: Reference Image:]

**Any suggestions to take backup of TimescaleDB hypertables?**

Comment: This is just a notice. Have you verified that the backup is not in the dump file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In TimescaleDB, the hypertable is an empty table and the data is stored in child tables called *chunks*. You can see the structure of the hypertable using the `\d+` command in `psql`:

```
postgres=# \d+ devices
                                          Table "public.devices"
 Column |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Stats target | Description 
--------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+--------------+-------------
 time   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |         | plain   |              | 
 device | integer                  |           | not null |         | plain   |              | 
 temp   | double precision         |           |          |         | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "devices_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("time", device)
    "devices_device_time_idx" btree (device, "time" DESC)
    "devices_time_idx" btree ("time" DESC)
Triggers:
    ts_insert_blocker BEFORE INSERT ON devices FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION _timescaledb_internal.insert_blocker()
Child tables: _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_10_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_11_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_12_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_13_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_14_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_15_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_1_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_2_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_3_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_4_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_5_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_6_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_7_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_8_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._dist_hyper_1_9_chunk
```

When you dump a table using PostgreSQL `pg_dump`, it will dump the contents of the parent table and the child tables separately. When you restore the dump it will in turn fill both the hypertable (parent table) and the chunks (child tables).

Since `pg_dump` uses the standard `COPY` command to extract the contents of tables when dumping, TimescaleDB prints a notice that you're trying to dump a hypertable, which is empty.

The reasons for this is that if you do a direct dump of the hypertable *only* using `COPY`, it will not dump any data at all, which is useful to know since it's easy to make a mistake otherwise. Since it is not possible to distinguish between the case that you run `COPY` to on a single table directly and using `pg_dump` (which dumps all tables), this notice will be printed also when you use `pg_dump`, but it is harmless.

You should check the actual dump output to see that the child tables are actually dumped.

Answer (score 0):

In order to duplicate the schema, I used the following flow:

1. `pg_dump` source schema into sql
2. `sed` to replace source to target in the dump
3. `psql` to target schema

The above three steps can be performed as a one liner: `pg_dump | sed | psql`

These steps don't create hypertables as the underlying tables are actually in internal timescaledb schema.

To create and load the data, generate the following steps from  timescaledb_information.dimensions view:

1. `drop trigger ts_insert_blocker on <target>.<hypertable_name>;`
2. `SELECT ts_config.create_hypertable('<target>.<hypertable_name>', 'timestamp', chunk_time_interval => 3600000000);`
3. `psql -c "\copy (select * from <source>.<hypertable_name>) to STDOUT "| psql -c "\copy <target>.<hypertable_name> from STDIN "`